# How to add vertical section highlighter to the web page? Is there any name for such scrolling section? Can it be done via BootStrap?

Tags: html, css, navigation, bootstrap

I would like to add a vertical scrollbar based navigation to my single page website to indicate to the user which section they are currently in. which looks something like this:

[image]

I would like to add it to the right side of my web page so users know where exactly they are and if they click on a particular dot, they are navigated to a particular section.

Is there any name for such a navigation bar?

Can it be done using the bootstrap?

Do we have some direct default template which I can use directly?

Reference website page: [Free Vector Template](https://www.freepik.com/free-vector/global-logistics-solutions-isometric-landing-page_10385759.htm?query=supply%20chain%20management)

Answer (score 2):

That component is generally called a [timeline](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/extended/timeline/)

here is an [example](https://codepen.io/cjl750/pen/XMyRoB) of a responsive timeline (horizontal)

There is also something called [scrollspy](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/scrollspy/#example-with-nested-nav) which is responsive to scroll position, which could be modified to meet your needs